# Python replace non digit character in a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, dataframe

I have the following dataframe column

```
>>> df2['Age]

1    25
2    35
3    48 y
4    34 yea
5    29
...
```

I just want to keep the number en replace the value in df2['Age] like that

```
1    25
2    35
3    48
4    34
5    29
...
```

My code doesn't work :

```
df2.Age.replace('^.*','^[0-9]*[0-9]',regex=True,inplace=True)
```

here's the result

```
 1    ^[0-9]*[0-9]
 2    ^[0-9]*[0-9]
 3    ^[0-9]*[0-9]
 4    ^[0-9]*[0-9]
 5    ^[0-9]*[0-9]
 ...
```

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `\D+` for replace non numeric to empty string:

```
df2.Age.replace('\D+','',regex=True,inplace=True)
print (df2)
  Age
1  25
2  35
3  48
4  34
5  29
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.extract`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Age": ['25', '35', '48 y', '34 yea', '29']})
df["Age"] = df["Age"].str.extract(r"(\d+)", expand=False)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Age
0  25
1  35
2  48
3  34
4  29
```