# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'

Tags: pandas, filtering, numeric

I have a pandas df and I want to remove non-numeric values of `col1`.

If I use `df[df.col1.apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric())]`, I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'`

any suggestion on doing this efficiently in pandas?

Comment: strings have an `isnumeric()` attribute, but a float clearly doesn't need one because it _has_ to be numeric. You probably have an Object column where some values are strings, and others are missing and `NaN` is a float, so add some error handling like `if not pd.isnull(x)`. (But really you should do this with `pd.to_numeric` instead of Series.apply)

Comment: so how can I drop string values from this column?

Answer (score 1):

You could use standard method of strings `isnumeric` and apply it to each value in your `id` column:
[Remove non-numeric rows in one column with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961028/remove-non-numeric-rows-in-one-column-with-pandas)
[Python replace non digit character in a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517023/python-replace-non-digit-character-in-a-dataframe)